# On-hold question is not editable and comments are disabled; why?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions, migration

[How do I prevent myself from leaning too close to the monitor?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/14206/325) is currently on hold.  The "edit" link is not available (this isn't a rep problem), and comments are disabled.  The post is behaving as if it's locked, but there's no "locked" banner.

This was migrated from another site and then put on hold here.  I suspect that's relevant, as other on-hold questions (like [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/14200/325), for instance) have comments and editing enabled.

This seems like a bug.  How can the question be fixed if we can't comment or edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a migrated question is closed on the target site, it is a "rejected migration". The question is locked, and automatically deleted after a period of time. If you think such a question can be salvaged, you can flag a mod to unlock it.

Comment: If it were *closed* that's what I would expect (I couldn't remember if they got deleted), but should that happen while it's on hold?  I guess it seems like it should either be deleted entirely or left in a state where people could try to help it, since it's only been on this site for a few hours.  (Note: I don't myself have an edit in mind; it just struck me as odd that anybody who does want to help can't, short of flaagging.)  Anyway, thanks for explaining what happened!

Comment: The "on-hold" phase is a recent addition; perhaps it would make sense to change this behavior now that it's been introduced. I think [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) would be the appropriate place to discuss such a proposal, if you'd like to bring it up there.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio [Close notification on rejected migrations doesn't make much sense](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195653/close-notification-on-rejected-migrations-doesnt-make-much-sense)

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and unlocked the post. The one line answers that I saw made me think it wasn't really going to be a good question for our site. It had the classic feel of a "poll", so I closed it.

When migrated questions are closed, answers from the migration source are all automatically deleted, and the post is automatically locked. When I saw that the one-line answers were all from the other community and were deleted, I realized that I probably should have just removed the other answers instead.

The post in it's current form isn't strong enough for me to justify reopening it, but I went ahead and unlocked the post to give our community an opportunity to make their edits and cast reopen votes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  The question clearly needs work, and I don't have a proposed edit ready or anything like that.  The situation puzzled me, is all.